# How to align right social media icon with navbar-collapse in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align social media icon with my navbar menu to 
the right but it is not working there is a gap when I am doing 
it.

The social icon is in a separate row
The navbar is also in a separate row
I just want to align them to the right.

The padding-right and pull-right is not working.
Please help, Thank you very much in advance.

CSS code

```
.navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

HTML codes

```
<div class="row" style="height: 40px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="social pull-right">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-phone"></i></a>+65 652 225 25</li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-weixin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope-o"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Navigation Menu and Carousel -->
<div class="row" style="background-color: black">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="img">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="clients.html">WORKS</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com">Google+</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add 'text-right' class in li

Comment: can you give us the link of your source code on JsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.social ul li{
       float:right;
list-style:none;
padding-right:15px
    }


<div class="social col-lg-6 pull-right">
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/7UrmRCoXrT)

Comment: it is working dude but the icons change also phone goes to the right.

Comment: @JunarAquiJacob Helpers are hard getting your question. If you can't tweak this, then please clarify what do you want to achieve.

Comment: i just tweak it sir @5ervant thanks for your comment

Comment: @JunarAquiJacob remove `col-lg-6` from `<div` . and change `float:right` to `float:left`. finally add css for `.social{ width:30%; }`. Ex: http://www.bootply.com/XJ9dfoHH7E

Comment: i am happy with first answer @ArunKumar your second answer is not working on me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using the navbar-right class from Bootstrap:

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.html">WORKS</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com">Google+</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com">LinkedIn</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>

            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-phone"></i></a>+65 652 225 25</li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-weixin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope-o"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: Check out Bootstrap documentation and look for the navbar-right class. There is an example here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default.